# Udpate object in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to update a object in elasticsearch, but I'm having the next error message:

> Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object
>   mapping for [errorMessages] tried to parse field [errorMessages] as
>   object, but found a concrete value]

```
This is my mappings:

{
.hierarchies: {
  mappings: {
   hierarchy: {
    dynamic: "strict",
   _all: {
      enabled: false
    },
    properties: {
      errorFlag: {
       type: "keyword"
     },
      errorMessages: {
        properties: {
           isFavourite: {
             type: "text"
        },
          message: {
             type: "text"
         }
       }
     },

  }
 }
}
```

And the information that I'm trying to update is this:

```
"errorMessages" -> "{"isFavourite":"yes","message":"hola"}"
```

I use the rest client connector and the object UpdateRequest:

```
 UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest(
                collection,
                type,
                id);

        updateRequest.doc(document);
        updateRequest.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE);
        try {
            return esConnector.getRestClient().update(
                    updateRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ElasticsearchGenericException("Error updating document " + collection + " > " + type + " id: " + id + " (Reason: " + e.getMessage() + ")");
        }
    }
```

The value of the document is the json with the errorMessages.
And this is the UpdateRequest object:

> update {[.hierarchies][hierarchy][ZEqi1GkByxIcUBtfsLRV],
>   doc_as_upsert[false], doc[index {[null][null][null],
>   source[{"errorMessages":"{\"isFavourite\":\"yes\",\"message\":\"hola\"}"}]}],
>   scripted_upsert[false], detect_noop[true]}

Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`errorMessages` should be represented an array of objects as below and not as string value:

```
{
  "errorMessages": [
    {
      "isFavourite": "yes",
      "message": "hola"
    }
  ]
}
```